# Can we replace the GitHub Profile field with Steam ID?

Tags: feature-request, user-profile, steam

New profiles are here! Yay! There are fields for relevant social links like Twitter and... GitHub?

I mean, GitHub makes tons of sense over on the mothership, but here at Arqade, we're about using software, not making it. And a Steam Profile is something that would fit pretty perfectly in the same space. It'd be a Nice Thing To Have here at Gaming.SE, so howzaboutit?

Comment: 100x ^This + Twitch/Youtube channels as well.

Comment: I'm surprised this wasn't implemented straight up.

Comment: Even on SO, people want links to other code-hosting sites.  [I commented on one such feedback answer to ask for Steam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features?page=4&tab=active#comment817418_250355).  Oded said it's "planned" for "one day in the future".

Comment: What about games not just on Steam though?  You have uPlay, Origin, etc