# Can the profile 'website link' be made to render Steam/YouTube/Twitch channel names like the Twitter one does?

Tags: feature-request, user-profile, hyperlinks

I was updating my profile and I noticed that we now support links to Twitter, Which render the name of the feed quite nicely on the profile itself:

[image: Adding websites to profile]
[image: Twitter on the profile page]

This is great! My question is: could we do this with Steam/YouTube/Twitch channels that are linked in the 'website link' field? As you may have noticed above, this currently looks a little ugly:

[image: Ugly Youtube channel link]

(We could also [replace the Github field entirely](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10440/can-we-replace-the-github-profile-field-with-steam-id), but that's a larger change).

Comment: Side note: That third image features the best freehand circle I've ever drawn with a mouse. :P

Comment: Freehand circles shouldn't be well draw... -1!

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau haha true